# Getting Java Layout Managers to Behave with JTextFields and JLabels

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, flowlayout, boxlayout

I'm having a little bit of trouble getting Java's Swing layout managers to behave. This is my first time trying to create a GUI of my own, so it's likely I've just missed something fairly simple, however I would appreciate any advice that can be offered up.

What I am trying to create is a custom JPanel that contains JLabels and JTextFields to allow the user to enter an IP address (so four JTextFields interspaced with three JLabels containing a '.')

I am finding really difficult to find a layout manager that will set this up as I would like; I have tried a Flow and a Box layout and as neither of these worked I have also tried a GridBag, which I thought was perhaps overkill, but even that doesn't work right.

Here is my code that starts the class:

```
public class PingPanel extends JPanel {
    private JLabel[] dotLabels;
    private JTextField[] pingFields;

    public PingPanel() {
        Dimension dim = getPreferredSize();
        dim.width = 400;
        setPreferredSize(dim);

        dotLabels = new JLabel[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < dotLabels.length; i++) {
            dotLabels[i] = new JLabel(".");
        }

        pingFields = new JTextField[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < pingFields.length; i++) {
            pingFields[i] = new JTextField(3);
        }

        Border panelBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        setBorder(panelBorder);

        //setupFlow();
        //setupBox();
        //setupGridBag();
```

I've only set the panel's width to 400 to try and get everything to display (as you'll see in a moment I'm not having much luck with that either.) I understand that some of the managers ignore preferred sizes anyway, which is probably why this doesn't work. I've created three methods to try the different layout managers; here they are with the effect that they produce:

```
public void setupFlow() {
    for (int p = 0; p < pingFields.length; p++) {
        if (p == dotLabels.length) {
            add(pingFields[p]);
            System.out.println(p + " (Final Column)");
        }

        else {
            add(pingFields[p]);
            add(dotLabels[p]);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

The FlowLayout produces this:

[image: FlowLayout]

This is the closest to what I want it to look like, but I'm not sure why I only get one JTextField and one Label.

```
public void setupBox() {
    Container pingBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();

    for (int p = 0; p < pingFields.length; p++) {
        if (p == dotLabels.length) {
            pingBox.add(pingFields[p]);
            System.out.println(p + " (Final Column)");
        }

        else {
            pingBox.add(pingFields[p]);
            pingBox.add(dotLabels[p]);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Box Layout]

This is what BoxLayout gives me. I literally have no idea how I've messed this one up so badly!

```
public void setupGridBag() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.gridy = 0;
    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.weightx = 1.0;
    gc.weighty = 1.0;
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

    add(pingFields[0], gc);

    gc.gridx++;
    add(dotLabels[0], gc);

    gc.gridx++;
    add(pingFields[1], gc);

    gc.gridx++;
    add(dotLabels[1], gc);

    gc.gridx++;
    add(pingFields[2], gc);

    gc.gridx++;
    add(dotLabels[2], gc);

    gc.gridx++;
    add(pingFields[3], gc);
}
```

[image: GridBag]

The GridBagLayout at least gives me the layout I'm looking for, but I've not been able to work out how to make the JTextFields wider.

So there we are - I'm sure my green-ness has just caused me to miss something obvious, but I would be really grateful if anyone had any ideas.

Comment: you could set the MinimumSize to a default width, but this wouldn´t be the best way either.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: I apologise, I hadn't realised that I hadn't provided enough information.

Comment: I've managed to fix the issue - apparently removing the code to setPreferredSize has made both the FlowLayout and the GridBagLayout work as they should. The BoxLayout still looks pretty horrendous, but there's no need to worry about that now.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `GridBagLayout` is what you'd after. Think it as a grid based layout with custom alignment for each component; also each component can occupy multiple columns and rows, enabling quite custom set up.

I got a bit sample code as below:

```
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[] {30, 30, 60, 60, 60, 30, 30};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] {18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] {0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] {0.125, 0.125, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.125, 0.125};
    setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JLabel labelLong = new JLabel("Long");
    labelLong.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    labelLong.setFont(DisplayConstants.FONT_PANEL_LABEL_BOLD);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_labelLong = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_labelLong.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_labelLong.gridx = 0;
    gbc_labelLong.gridy = 0;
    add(labelLong, gbc_labelLong);

    JLabel labelShort = new JLabel("Short");
    labelShort.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    labelShort.setFont(DisplayConstants.FONT_PANEL_LABEL_BOLD);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_labelShort = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_labelShort.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_labelShort.gridx = 6;
    gbc_labelShort.gridy = 0;
    add(labelShort, gbc_labelShort);
```

If you are just after a simple layout, then the `BorderLayout` is what you'd do. Place the fixed size component at side and the major component at center.

Also, it's worthy to mention that Java uses the `setPreferredSize()` for each component to specify additional size parameters, so the GUI layout would try its best to satisfy the preferred size for each component. Call `JFrame.pack()` after your construction is finished to arrange component, too.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that a BorderLayout wouldn't work for my PingPanel, as I am trying to line seven components up in a row?

Comment: @lordchancellor Correct. GridBagLayout is for this. You can create really complex custom layout with it.